# Solr Typeahead feature implementation

Tags: java, web-applications, solr, typeahead

I am trying to implement type-ahead feature in my search engine using solr(index core name is "people") and have done the following configuration changes in my solrconfig.xml:

```
<queryResponseWriter name="tah"
class="com.sample.TypeAheadResponseWriter"/>
<requestHandler name="/type-ahead"
    class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="wt">tah</str>
        <str name="defType">dismax</str>
        <str name="qf"> wordPrefix^1.0 </str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

My schema file fields

```
<field name="wordPrefix" type="prefix" />
<copyField source="name" dest="wordPrefix"/>
```

Below is the content of my com.sample.TypeAheadResponseWriter

```
public class TypeAheadResponseWriter implements QueryResponseWriter {
    private Set<String> fields;

    @Override
    public String getContentType(SolrQueryRequest req, SolrQueryResponse solrQueryResponse) {
        return "text/html;charset=UTF-8";
    }

    public void init(NamedList n) {
        fields = new HashSet<String>();
        fields.add("word");
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Writer w, SolrQueryRequest req, SolrQueryResponse rsp) throws IOException {
        SolrIndexSearcher searcher = req.getSearcher();
        NamedList nl = rsp.getValues();
        int sz = nl.size();
        for (int li = 0; li < sz; li++) {
            Object val = nl.getVal(li);
            if (val instanceof DocList) {
                DocList dl = (DocList) val;
                DocIterator iterator = dl.iterator();
                w.append("<ul>n");
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    int id = iterator.nextDoc();
                    Document doc = searcher.doc(id, fields);
                    String name = doc.get("name");
                    w.append("<li>" + name + "</li>n");
                }
                w.append("</ul>n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not getting any response on hitting URL

```
http://<hostname>:8983/solr/people/type-ahead?q=Reb.
```

But when I change the value of wt to json in my solrconfig.xml, it do get the response. I tried everything I possibly could. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, trouble located here:

```
if (val instanceof DocList) {
```

Let's look at last lines from `QueryComponent.process`:

```
ResultContext ctx = new ResultContext();
ctx.docs = rb.getResults().docList;
ctx.query = rb.getQuery();
rsp.add("response", ctx);
```

So `DocList` is located in `rsp.getValues().get("response").docs`